# Is there a way to set human readable text and font type and size in zxing barcode library?

Tags: java, zxing

I would like to generate barcode (code39) using zxing library in Java. Is there way to set human readable text and font type and size? Like, I want to use ARIALUNI.TTF font and size should be 12pt for my barcode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ZXING library does not support human readable text as OkapiBarcode (https://github.com/woo-j/OkapiBarcode) or barcode4j. Please, let me know, if ZXING supports human readable text.

If you need more control to generate the barcode then use barcode4j. However, barcode4j is old library. As far as I know, there is no new update after 2012.